# jquery datatable is not honouring manually inserted new row

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using Jquery datatable, I need to add new rows in mid,  for that I have added new using $(row).after(rowData)(As datatable doesn't have any API for this).
After this when I perform sort(click on different header), newly added rows vanished. Even I have tried to re-draw (table.fnDraw()) table again after added newly row, but it didn't work(again vanished after redraw operation).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an original set of data (I will call this Data1), which is being used to create the table, and then you are adding additional rows using information from a separate set of data (Data2). The "sort" function is only aware of Data1, so sorting it produces a sorted result showing only Data1.

You need to insert Data2 into Data1 (that is, add the additional rows to both the data source and the mark-up) so that Data1 contains all information. Then sorting should work.

If you provide some info about the data format you are using (e.g object, array, call on an API) then maybe we can see how to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly, I am getting JSON format data (data1), for second  User can input manually (as its input form), I just found link https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html, which may help in this scenario, I will try and let you know I it works, Thank you.